# Python continue reading log file with filters and write filter data to a new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a script to Continue read a log file (Similar to tail -f in linux) with specific filters, and when the filters match with log file loggings, it should write matched filters to new file and then restart from where it left off instead of reading the log file again.

Sample log file:

```
2020-04-10 20:37:05,331 - INFO - 
2020-04-10 20:37:05,341 - INFO - 
2020-04-10 20:37:05,349 - INFO - 
2020-04-10 20:37:05,358 - WARNING - data missing: 
2020-04-10 20:37:05,359 - INFO - 
2020-04-10 20:37:05,366 - WARNING - data missing: 
2020-04-10 20:37:05,366 - WARNING - data missing: 
2020-04-10 20:37:05,367 - INFO - 
2020-04-10 20:37:05,375 - INFO -
```

Filter string: `WARNING - data missing:`

Code that i'm working on

```
import os

mylines = []
with open ('file.log', 'rt') as myfile:
    for myline in myfile:
        mylines.append(myline.rstrip('\n'))

index = 0
prev = 0
str = mylines[0]
substr = "WARNING - data missing:"
while index < len(str):
    index = str.find(substr, index)
    if index == -1:
        break
    print(" " * (index - prev) + "WARNING - data missing:", end='')
    prev = index + len(substr)
    index += len(substr)
print('\n' + str);

if not os.path.exists('/tmp/.fileinfo'):
    seek_from = 0
else: 
    of = open('/tmp/.fileinfo', 'r')
    seek_from = int(of.readline().strip())
```

Can some suggest a way to write filters to another file and if there is any other way to get what i want

Comment: if the filter string is `WARNING - data missing:` then you want to write the log entries  from the `file.log` which contain the filer string to the other log file? Am i understood correctly?

Comment: Yes, i want to write filter string to new file and go back to file.log to search for same string from where you left

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
with open("file.log", "r") as inlog, open("filtered.log", "w") as outlog:
    for log in inlog:
        log = log.strip()
        if "WARNING - data missing:" in log:
            outlog.write(log + "\n")
```